# video_player package not able to play mp4-files on iOS but android

Tags: ios, flutter, video-player

I am downloading mp4 file from Firestore.
Then I sure it in the Cache with the ChaceManager. Like:

```
 dev.log(name: 'Resource_Explorer', 'Trying to chace Video: $videoName');
      final storageRef = _firebaseStorage.ref(path);
      final fileData = await storageRef.getData();
      return ExplorerFileInfo(await cacheinstance.putFile(path, fileData!, key: path), FileState.downloaded);
```

Then I provide the Video to my Video Player as:

```
final videoFile = (await resourceExplorer.getVideoFile(videoPath)).value;
```

Everything works fine on Android. But on IOS im getting the error:
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(VideoError, Failed to load video: Cannot Open, null, null)

I searched for the error 'Failed to load video: Cannot Open' and found GitHub issue which is still open. but only one person had the same 'Cannot Open' as me. They are getting error like: 'Failed to load video: Operation Stopped,'. And this issue is still unsolved. And seems to be a Http error.

I am able to play the same video from my assets. And I am able to do the same steps to display an Image on IOS and on Android.

I would be greatful for any help. Thanks in advance!

---

Update:
After I downloaded the file with the Duo package instead of .getData(), I was able to deliver the file as wished mp4 and play it with the video_player. 
But if I safe the data in the cache with the cache manager, I will get the data as .file and video_player is not able to play .file files on iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, the issue is that you are not setting the file extension when the file gets saved in the cache.

The **putFile** method of the **DefaultCacheManager** saves sets the file extension to **.file** by default, this makes it impossible for **iOS** to play the video.

The solution is to update the **putFile** method specifying a **fileExtension**, like so:

```
return ExplorerFileInfo(await cacheinstance.putFile(path, fileData!, key: path, fileExtension: 'mp4'), FileState.downloaded);
```

This way you don't need to update the file name like you described in your solution.

Comment: I will try to check this the days, ty for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the Problem.

Somehow is video_player able to open "*.file" on Android, but on iOS!

To solve the problem you have to rename your videoFile like:

```
      final videoFile = (await resourceExplorer.getVideoFile(videoPath)).value;
      String videoFilePath = videoFile.path;
      String videoFilePathAsMp = '${videoFilePath.substring(0, videoFilePath.length - 4)}mp4';
      final renamedVideo = await videoFile.rename(videoFilePathAsMp);
      _vpController = VideoPlayerController.file(renamedVideo)
        ..addListener(() => setState(() {}))
        ..setLooping(true)
        ..setVolume(0.0)
        ..initialize().then((_) => _vpController!.play());
```